# React setState in two Async functions, second overwrites first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an interesting problem here I will try to outline here.  I have a state object in React state that is updated in two separate async functions in this way:

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({})

const somefunction1 = async () => {
  const res1 = ///some api call
  setSomeState({...someState, res1: res1})
}

const somefunction2 = async () => {
  const res2 = ///some api call
  setSomeState({...someState, res2: res2})
}

await someFunction1();
await someFunction2();

console.log(someState); //{res2: res2}
```

Based on the above example, I am not sure why res1 is missing in this state object when they are called separately, the second call effectively overwrites the changes made from the first call.  What I really need this to look like when its done is:

```
console.log(someState); //{res1: res1, res2: res2}
```

Is there a better way to write this scenario so I get the expected outcome?  Since one somefunction2 is supposed to wait until somefunction1 is complete, I am not sure why it is overwriting it.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Use a callback instead for the second state setter, so you can incorporate the already-changed state when setting the second time

Comment: ^`setSomeState((someState) => ({ ...someState, res1-2 }))`